# Android capture picture from WebView is not working in Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, html, webview, bitmap, screenshot

I need to take a picture from html code. (convert HTML to Bitmap).

For this task I'm using this code and it works fine for most of apis besides API 23

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);

...

void saveHtmlImage(final PrintData data) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            //view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
                            picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    picture.draw(c);

                    data.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    callback.callingBack(data);
                }
            }, 500);

        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(true);

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<TABLE border=\"1\"\n" +
            "          summary=\"This table gives some statistics about fruit\n" +
            "                   flies: average height and weight, and percentage\n" +
            "                   with red eyes (for both males and females).\">\n" +
            "<CAPTION><EM>A test table with merged cells</EM></CAPTION>\n" +
            "<TR><TH rowspan=\"2\"><TH colspan=\"2\">Average\n" +
            "    <TH rowspan=\"2\">Red<BR>eyes\n" +
            "<TR><TH>height<TH>weight\n" +
            "<TR><TH>Males<TD>1.9<TD>0.003<TD>40%\n" +
            "<TR><TH>Females<TD>1.7<TD>0.002<TD>43%\n" +
            "</TABLE>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

#### Android 5.1.0

Capture Picture is working

[image: image description]

#### Android 6.0.1

Capture Picture is NOT working

[image: image description]

Comment: Convert html to bitmap? Please explain.

Comment: Rasterize html markup. Create image from html.

Comment: Where are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, about what you?